# ASP.NET Chart Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, aspchart

On a page (I've called Cashflow.aspx) I have an asp.net chart to plot out some data. It works wonderfully when debugging on my local machine. However, when I try to deploy the site to my staging server there is an error that I can't seem to track down. It fails and redirects back to my default.aspx page. If I comment out the chart and deploy again the rest of the page works just fine.

**aspx Page:**

```
<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">


<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading">Cashflow</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Width="1400px" Height="500px">
                    <Series>
                        <asp:Series Name="As Bid Projected Cashflow" ChartType="Line" ChartArea="ChartArea1" BorderWidth="3" BorderColor="#86a44a"></asp:Series>
                        <asp:Series Name="Actual Cashflow" ChartType="Line" ChartArea="ChartArea1" BorderWidth="3" BorderColor="#da8137"></asp:Series>
                    </Series>
                    <ChartAreas>
                        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" />
                    </ChartAreas>
                </asp:Chart>
            </div><div class="row">&nbsp;</div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</asp:Content>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace MySite
{
    public partial class Cashflow : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    DataTable tbl;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            LoadData();
            decimal maxValue = 0;

            Chart1.DataSource = tbl;
            Chart1.Series["As Bid Projected Cashflow"].XValueMember = "Period";
            Chart1.Series["As Bid Projected Cashflow"].YValueMembers = "AsBidProjectedCashflow";
            Chart1.Series["Actual Cashflow"].XValueMember = "Period";
            Chart1.Series["Actual Cashflow"].YValueMembers = "ActualCashflow";
            Chart1.Series["Actual Cashflow"].Sort(PointSortOrder.Ascending);

            Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = 45;
            Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "C";
            Chart1.Legends.Add("As Bid Projected Cashflow");
            Chart1.Legends["As Bid Projected Cashflow"].Position.Auto = false;
            Chart1.Legends["As Bid Projected Cashflow"].Position = new ElementPosition(0, 0, 30, 15);
            Chart1.Legends["As Bid Projected Cashflow"].Docking = Docking.Right;
            Chart1.Legends["As Bid Projected Cashflow"].DockedToChartArea = "ChartArea1";
            Chart1.Legends["As Bid Projected Cashflow"].IsDockedInsideChartArea = false;
            Chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.Auto = false;
            Chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position = new ElementPosition(0, 15, 105, 85);
            Chart1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString;
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        tbl = new DataTable();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("GetCashflow", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(tbl);
    }

    protected void btnRefreshCharts_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Cashflow.aspx?pnum=" + Request.QueryString["pnum"]);
    }
}
}
```

**(Relevant) Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="ChartImg.axd"  type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"  />
    </httpHandlers>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6">
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
      </buildProviders>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="262144000" executionTimeout="110" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting"
      assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <!--<modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>-->
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
      <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode"  verb="GET,HEAD,POST"
    path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory  type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

**Network Monitor**
[image]

All relevant dlls are installed and up to date. Not really sure where to look next to track down the issue. Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Memory or a File to render the chart each time?  I seem to recall there being an option to specify which and in the case of File, permissions may  be an issue.

Comment: That was the issue. I was using a file.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change this line in my web.config from:

```
<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;" />
```

to:

```
<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=memory;deleteAfterServicing=true;" />
```